# Gorm findallby date tip

Tags: grails, date, grails-orm

any quick tip to implement findAllByGreaterThan so I can filter those records which date field is today (from 00:00 up to present).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like (assuming Book is a domain class)

```
Book.findAll("from Book b where b.lastCheckedOut >= current_date()")
```

It may work as

```
Book.findAllGreaterThanEquals("current_date()")
```